# Range loop over any data structure

Tags: c++, templates

I have the next idea - make it possible to iterate over any container (both sequence and associative) using range-based loop.

I only came to decision like this:

```
template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Container<Args...>& c) {
//  for (const auto& element : c) {
//  for (const auto&[key, value] : c) {
//      s << element << ' ';
//      s << key << ' ' << value << ' ';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Is it possible in some way to do something semantically similar to:

```
for (const auto&[args...] : c) { recv_parameter_pack_or_tuple(args...); }
```

?

Comment: `const auto& element` works with both associative and sequence containers.

Comment: For the second use-case, where you call `recv_parameter_pack_or_tuple`, then you can have two overloads of the function: One taking a single value, and one taking a `std::pair`. The first will be used for sequence containers, and the other for the associative containers.

Comment: yes, but how to make universal access for both types of data structures? For sequence we need `for (const auto& element : c)  stream << element;` syntax, for associative we need `for (const auto& element : c) stream << element.first << element.second;` syntax.

Comment: @385i You can have two different implementations for a function with different argument types by using overloading.

Comment: For the use-case or writing to a stream, call an overloaded function to do the actual writing.

Answer (score 0):

It was all mentioned in comments already: The range based loop can look always the same, because all containers have a single `value_type`. To print the elements you can use overloads.

When overloading `<<` for `std::ostream` I'd add a wrapper, because it can cause issues to overload operators for types that arent yours (alternatively write a `my_print(...)` and drop the wrapper):

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct my_wrapper {
    const T& t;
    my_wrapper(const T& t) : t(t) {}
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const my_wrapper<T>& m){ return o << m.t; }

template <typename F,typename S>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const my_wrapper<std::pair<const F,S>>& m){
    return o << m.t.first << " " << m.t.second;
}

int main() {

    std::map<int,int> m{{1,2},{3,4}};

    for (const auto& e : m ){ std::cout << my_wrapper{e}; }

    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};

    for (const auto& e : v ){ std::cout << my_wrapper{e}; }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sKTYMP3aG)